# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2 and basic authentication together

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I am impementing asp .net mvc project that will use token authentication. I also want users to be able to login by their Google account as well as providing login/password on my website. I have made some inquiries and the best solution seems to be DotNetOpenAuth library. I cannot, however, find any examples how to implement both basic authentication with token for users not wanting to use their google account and OAuth in one project. Can anybody show me example or reference that I can make use of?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047615/how-do-i-manage-my-authentication-with-worlddomination-and-nancy/18059752#18059752 This may help. It's specific to SimpleAuthentication, same applies.

Answer (score 0):

A good example https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/basicoauth2server.persistent

I hope you help.